# Why does object not reference other object after unserialize?

Tags: php

```
    $obj = new classname();
    $obj1 = $obj;
    $obj->var = 'something';
    $obj = unserialize(serialize($obj));
    $obj->var= 'something new';
```

Now obj1->var = 'something' and $obj->var = 'something new'.

Why does $obj,$obj1 not reference to the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

The function `unserialize` acts like an alternative constructor. It will always create a new object.

Comment: what about its properties before unserialize?

Comment: There are no properties. It is an entirely new object with its properties filled in by the values found inside the string argument.

Answer (score 0):

When you did `$obj = unserialize(serialize($obj));`, you created a new object.